# Why does 'loss' change depending on the number of epochs chosen?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am using Keras to train different NN. I would like to know why if I increment the epochs in 1, the result until the new epoch is not the same. I am using shuffle=False, and np.random.seed(2017), and I have check that if I repeat with the same number of epochs, the result is the same, so not random initialization is working.

Here I attach the picture of the resulting training with 2 epochs:

[image]
And here I attach the picture of the resulting training with 3 epochs:

[image]

Also, I would like to know why the training time is not (3/2) and how is it possible that some of them have less accuracy with one more epoch.

**UPDATED**

Here is the link to open code Jupyter Notebook. [GitHub Jupyter Notebook - ANN Comparison](https://github.com/PabloRR100/Pruning-Algorithm-Method/blob/master/NN-Comparison.ipynb)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure you removed all randomness? Is the backend tensorflow?

Comment: Hi Maxim, thanks for reply. Do you mean randomness in the generation of the data? Yes, it is tf backend.

https://github.com/PabloRR100/Pruning-Algorithm-Method/blob/master/NN-Comparison.ipynb

Here you can find the code as well. Thanks for helping me and I hope it also helps you

Comment: I mean `np.random.seed` is not enough. Tensorflow uses its own random generator. Set `tf.set_random_seed`. And make sure the result is the same if you run the same model twice.

Comment: Yes, Maxim. I have both numpy seed and tensorflow seed. Correct me if I am maybe making errors in the process. I just train the NNs with 10 epochs. See the evolution of loss. Delete the ANN and start them, everything the same but only 8 epochs. The result does not correspond to the 10 epochs graph until 8.